# Derby: The more rows in the tables, the faster the queries?

Tags: performance, optimization, benchmarking, derby

I noticed some strange behaviour while doing performance tests with Apache Derby DB:

I do five test runs for performance testing. Before each run, I insert some data in the table, so that I do the first run e.g. with 500k Tuples in the table, the second run with 1000k and the fifth run with 2500k tuples.

The execution times of the queries are something like this: 200ms, 450ms, 700ms, 500ms, 550ms

That is, the fourth run is faster than the third run, although more data has to be scanned and fetched in the fourth run. That's very weird.

The only reason I can imagine is that Derby optimizes some internal structures or the physical layout from time to time or as soon as the data in a table exceeds a certain threshold. Anyway, can trigger this optimization manually to get monotonically nondecreasing execution time measurements?

Or do you know the exact reason for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to learn how to read query plan output to figure out what's going on, but I'll venture a guess anyway: as rows are added to a table, the Derby server periodically notices that the table has changed substantially in size, and it automatically recomputes the statistics that the optimizer uses for query planning, which can result in completely different query plans.

To confirm this, you could try recomputing the statistics yourself after each data load, to see if you can get the best query plan: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tuning/ctunperfstatistics.html